# Android: How to change size of app:fabSize="normal" for Floating Action Button

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

When using the new `FloatingActionButton`, the size is determined by `app:fabSize="normal"`. How can I set what in `dp` is the size referenced by `"normal"`?

I tried to create `values/attrs.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="app">
        <attr name="fabSize">
            <enum name="mini" value="50dp" />
            <enum name="normal" value="100dp" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

But I get the error

```
"normal" in attribute "fabSize" is not a valid integer
```

Comment: These values are not changeable.

Comment: @EugenPechanec In general - do you know good link explains all the issues with app: and from where the world "normal" have it's meaning? Thanks,

Comment: "app" is usually a namespace for every attribute that's not defined by the android platform (which have "android" prefix"). ||| According to FloatingActionButton source fabSize is either 0 for normal size or 1 for mini size. So you can't override it this way. How big these are really is best described here: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There are two different sizes of `FAB` available: `normal` or `mini`

1. `Normal (56dp)` — This size should be used in most situations.
2. `Mini (40dp)` — Should only be used when there is a need for visual continuity with other components displayed on the screen.

Comment: Is there a way to change this defaults? In general - how to change the app: attributes?

Comment: Should only be used when there is a need for visual continuity with other components displayed on the screen -> What does that exactly means? Is there any example?

Comment: Where is the source for these constants?

Comment: Source: https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button

Comment: By the way, the inner icon size is 24dp by default no matter "normal" or "mini", which can also be found in the link above.

Answer (score 41):

You can override the normal and mini sizes by adding the following to `values/dimens.xml`:

```
<!-- Overriding sizes of the FAB -->
  <dimen name="design_fab_size_normal">90dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="design_fab_size_mini">30dp</dimen>
```

The tricky thing would be if you need more than 2 fab sizes, in that case i guess you need to create a custom view extending the fab.

Comment: You should also add `tools:override="true"` as these attributes are marked as private.

Comment: These are the default values:
    <dimen name="design_fab_size_normal">56dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_fab_size_mini">40dp</dimen>

Answer (score 33):

Just user app:fabCustomSize in xml

```
app:fabCustomSize="100dp"
```

Bingo.

Comment: While this attribute does appear to be in the docs for FAB, trying to set it leads a to a build error ("attribute not found").

Comment: did you declared app namespace like this => xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: Yes, with no success.

Comment: I updated all my material design libraries, and now this is showing.

Comment: Perfect Answer .

Answer (score 16):

I know it's not recommended, but for those that absolutely need to change the default sizes, I was able to do it by wrapping the `FloatingActionButton` in a `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="@dimen/custom_fab_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_fab_size"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_white_24dp"
        android:scaleType="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 12):

### • `Standard Sizes`

There are three options for standard `FAB` sizes (according to [developer.android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton)) which you can set them using `app:fabSize`.

1. **normal**: The normal sized button.
2. **mini**: The mini sized button.
3. **auto**: Size which will change based on the window size

.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
    app:tint="#404D54"
    app:backgroundTint="#ffd500"
    app:fabSize="normal" />
```

.

### • `Custom Sizes`

To set custom `FAB` size you can set `app:fabCustomSize`. Note that `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` should be `"wrap_content"`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
    app:tint="#404D54"
    app:backgroundTint="#ffd500"
    app:fabCustomSize="36dp" />
```

Answer (score 4):

app:maxImageSize

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_return_back"
    app:backgroundTint="#00ffffff"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:maxImageSize="46dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="0dp"
    app:rippleColor="#00ffffff" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<dimen name="design_fab_size_normal">90dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_fab_size_mini">30dp</dimen>
Set this in dimen file.
```

Comment: What's the added value over the [highest-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40242736/101361)?

Answer (score 0):

To change Fab size and to see large image init i have made below changes in android api 28:- thew are as

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/profile_imageview"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/design_fab_size_mini"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/design_fab_size_mini"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pin_check"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:maxImageSize="90dp" />
```

where in dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="design_fab_size_mini" tools:override="true">90dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_fab_content_size" tools:override="true">58dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `app:fabCustomSize="70dp"` in your xml file under FAB component

Here is an example of a FAB button :

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_AddRoom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.93"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.93" />
```