# FloatingActionButton shadow on pre-lollipop

Tags: android, shadow, floating-action-button

I want to make my `FloatingActionButton` much bigger with custom width and height. I find out that this is possible only if I add this as a child in `FrameLayout` or in `CoordinatorLayout`. On Lollipop and Marshmallow it looks good. But on pre-Lollipop the shadow from `FloatingActionButton` is very strange. Is it a bug from Android or I did something wrong?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/help_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/my_btn"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I also tried to add and `app:borderWidth="0dp"` but with no luck.

This is how it looks in Kitkat:

[image: Kitkat]

Comment: what about using width and height of layout as `wrap_content`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fab button is available under two default dimensions.
Normal (56dp),
Mini (40dp)

But you can override this values by adding followings code in dimens.xml (under values).

```
<dimen name="design_fab_size_normal">150dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_fab_size_mini">30dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is caused by these two lines:

```
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
```

Try setting them to:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Then add:

```
app:fabSize="normal"
```

So the final xml will be:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/help_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/my_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
        app:fabSize="normal"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah, but now the button isn't as big as I want to be

Comment: There are a couple of ways to change the size of fabs but it's recommended that you use the provided sizes even when trying to grow or shrink the button (i.e. normal, auto, or mini).

Here are some places where you can find the answer to changing the size: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882742/android-how-to-change-size-of-appfabsize-normal-for-floating-action-button

https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics/issues/143

I just put my fab in a FrameLayout and changed the size of the FrameLayout, personally.

Comment: I'll try it. But the problem is that I made a custom fab button that can get text, the solutions they provide are only for icons. I know that this is not efficient (the size and the text on fan button), but I just wanted to avoid the drawables.

Answer (score 0):

You should set

```
android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
```

and fabSize on mini(40dp) or normal(56dp). 
If you want different size of fab button you should scale the button.
E.g. if you want 48dp button size you should add

```
app:fabSize="mini"
android:scaleX=1.2
android:scaleY=1.2
```

Also if you want to keep image size set
    android:scaleType="center"