# Center image inside FAB

Tags: android, android-cardview, floating-action-button

A couple of days ago I had the perfect FAB, now the image won't be centered and it's driving me crazy!
this is what I got now:

[image]

i'm using the button inside a `CardView`. this is the button xml tag:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_options"
            style="@style/fab"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_options"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and this is the drawable file: ic_options.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M12,8c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM12,10c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2s0.9,2 2,2 2,-0.9 2,-2 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM12,16c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2s0.9,2 2,2 2,-0.9 2,-2 -0.9,-2 -2,-2z"/>
</vector>
```

weird thing is, when I change the FAB width and height to `wrap_content`, it gets centered properly but the button gets bigger and I don't want that.. like this:

[image]

this problem happened after I made some changes in the whole project, depending on Android Studio Inspector. But, this layout wasn't changed and I just have no idea what happened to it!

> Do you have any idea?

---

**Edit:**

CardView code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    app:ignore="NamespaceTypo"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    >


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription_mapBackground"
        android:foreground="@drawable/map_overlay" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/fab_margin"
        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_options"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:letterSpacing="0.04"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_marker2"
            android:drawableTint="@color/white"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="12sp" />


    </LinearLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_options"
            style="@style/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_options"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:fabCustomSize="40dp"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Just an idea since you haven't solved your problem: set this attribute `app:useCompatPadding="true"` to your fab. One more, does your activity class extend Activity instead of AppCompatActivity?

Comment: didn't work, my activity extends AppCompatActivity , and this CardView is actually a layout for an item in a recyclerview.

Comment: One more: in my app I have a recyclerview with cardviews as items and a fab inside a relative layout in  the cardview but the cardview is inside a vertical linearlayout and the fab icons are positioned as expected. If it's easy put the fab inside a layout or the cardview inside a layout. I know it does not make sense but your problem is so strange.

Comment: Thanks ! 
I actually put the cardview in a relative layout and took the fab outside of the cardview, and it works now !

Comment: @forpas if you will write your comment as an answer, i'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I already did and i'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my app I have a recyclerview with cardviews as items and a fab inside a relative layout in the cardview but the cardview is inside a vertical linearlayout and the fab icons are positioned as expected. 
If it's easy put the fab inside a layout or the cardview inside a layout. 
I know it does not make sense but your problem is so strange

Answer (score 9):

You can use `android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and `app:fabSize="mini"` or `app:fabCustomSize="40dp"`.

Does it suit you?

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work, but when I put the fab outside of the cardview (just to test it) it worked! 
but i don't know what's the problem with the cardview here .. I need the fab to be inside the cardview.

Answer (score 7):

Use `app:fabCustomSize` attribute instead of harcoding size.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_options"
    app:fabCustomSize="100dp"
    />
```

[image: output]

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work, but when I put the fab outside of the cardview (just to test it) it worked! but i don't know what's the problem with the cardview here .. I need the fab to be inside the cardview.

Comment: I'll test this case, and let you know the solution

Comment: Can you post your full code with CardView, you can remove unnecessary views before posting.

Comment: I edited my question and added the cardview code now.

Comment: Which version of support appcomact library you are using?

Comment: version is 28.0.0

Comment: When you use it inside CardView then icon is not at center?

Comment: Your layout code is working as expected my side, its size is large, and icon is in center. However you should try this solution, if you still can not get solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/40242736/6891563

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, the problem seemed to be because of the cardview, It's weird. but when I took the fab outside of the card view , it worked just fine using app:fabCustomSize="40dp" too. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had solved this problem like this:

```
android:fabSize="mini" // mini - 40dp
android:match_parent="40dp"
android:wrap_content="40dp"
```

So you should set size of fab button and android:match_parent 
android:wrap_content similar

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting image to cardview try adding imageview widget inside cardview along fab and then set gravity to center for imageview

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with FloatingActionButton from material and I was able to solve it by adding **maxImageSize** as following:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_print"
        app:maxImageSize="@dimen/_6m" />
```

Where src drawable size is 24 x 24 and dimen is 48dp.